# How to build Dockerfile with custom names

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I am trying to automate the building of Docker images. Let's say in a directory, there are several `Dockerfile` files. Some of them are named as `Dockerfile.test` or `Dockerfile_node` as there are multiple files in a single directory and they can't all be named `Dockerfile`.

I have a simple script which locates all those files and needs to call docker build.

This is the command I use for locating all the Dockerfile.

```
list=$(find . -name "Dockerfile*")
```

And I get the following list:

```
./Dockerfile1
./testing/Dockerfile
./testing/Dockerfile_kubernetes
```

In order to get the context, I need to find the directories that contain the `Dockerfile` files.

```
files=$(find . -name "Dockerfile*" -exec dirname {} \;)
```

For each Dockerfile, I am calling the `docker build`. Something like this...

```
for x in $files; do docker build $x; done;
```

I can't perform `docker build` as I get the following error.

```
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /home/ubuntu/repo/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

Running the `docker build` command will only build an image defined in `./testing/Dockerfile`.

I know it's bad practice to have multiple `Dockerfile` files in a single directory, and to name them like this, but I am not the one making these decisions. I just need to make it work.

Is there a way to build these Dockerfiles?

Comment: You mean like `find . -name "Dockerfile*" -execdir docker build -f {} . \;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the docker file name to build command.

```
for x in $files; do docker build -f $x .; done;
```

> By default the docker build command will look for a Dockerfile at the
> root of the build context. The -f, --file, option lets you specify the
> path to an alternative file to use instead

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

Comment: The lack of quoting is a bug, though.

Comment: Yes, this solved the issue.  Instead of looking for directories for the context purposes `files=$(find . -name "Dockerfile*" -exec dirname {} \;)` I only looked for the files `files=$(find . -name "Dockerfile*" )` and then `for x in $files; do docker build -f $x .; done;`. Thanks a lot.